# meu menu navega com tab normalmente, porém quando ativo o narrador do windows, o evento de keydown deixa de funcionar

Tags: windows, javascript-eventos, acessibilidade, event-listener

alguém saberia como solucionar este problema?

```js
const setListeners = () => {
    hamburguer.onclick = clicksSet.toggleMenu
    for(const [ name, { element, button, title, content, focused } ] of Object.entries(menulist)) {
        title.onclick = () => clicksSet.toggleItemsMenu(name, element, button, content, focused)
        button.onkeydown = e => { 
            if(e.key === "Enter" && document.activeElement !== menulist['Suggestion'].focused) 
            clicksSet.toggleItemsMenu(name, element, button, content, focused)
            console.log(document.activeElement)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.